# what is the technology of wired app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

i just want to know how an app can be made like wired ipad app?
what is its data? pdf , picture file, epub, html or whatever? i just want to know the way how can i display my data like wired app.

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one then one answer to this question, but the Wired iPad app is combination of XML, images and video.
The XML tells the reader how to dispaly the images and defines hit points, which can trigger an animation of display a video.

Comment: hm, its not PDF reader , is it? are all pages DHTML/XHTML? then it uses UIWebView to show content?

Comment: No, they use XML which tells there reader to set up the images. They the engine will display the magazine. There is NO HTML or PDF. You can use iphoneExplorer to check the document directory of the wired app and see all the resources.